# RxJS pipe chaining with IF statement in the middle

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, observable

I am getting a value, and based on the return, if data actually returned the first time I just send it through and carry on, else if nothing returns I get default values and carry on with the data.

My problem is returning the default data after the IF statement. I can not get it to return the data, instead of the observable/subscription

It looks something like this:

```
getValuesFunction() {
    const getFirstValues$ = this.ApiCall.getFirstValues();
    this.subscription = getFirstValues$.pipe(
        map(data => {
           if (data.length === 0) {
              // this line is the one I have a problem with
              return this.processedStockApi.getDefaultValues().subscribe();
           } else {
              // this line returns fine
              return data;
           }
        }),
        switchMap(data => this.apiCall.doSomethingWithData(data))
    ).subscribe();
}
```

// ApiCall

```
getDefaultValues() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.stockUrl + 'getSelectiveDeleteData');
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just instead of `map` use one of its variants that work with Observables like `concatMap` or `mergeMap` (`switchMap` will work as well in this situation):

```
getFirstValues$.pipe(
  concatMap(data => {
    if (data.length === 0) {
      // this line is the one I have a problem with
      return this.processedStockApi.getDefaultValues();
    } else {
      // this line returns fine
      return of(data);
    }
  }),
  switchMap(data => this.apiCall.doSomethingWithData(data)),
).subscribe(...);
```

Note that both `if-else` blocks now return Observables. It's `concatMap` who subscribes to them and emits their result further.

Comment: Very nice, they say to just learn a new operator every few weeks, and it seems I have now learned concatMap  :)

Comment: just make sure to understand that throwError() is not throw error
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/throwerror-is-not-throw-error-ad6c76c53377